# Lazy-load my whole site?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I'm wondering if this is possible: I want my whole site to delay until it is ready, then do a fadeIn. I'm not using continuous scrolling or anything like that. I just want my pages to display in a smoother, all-at-once style.

If I add a class="lazy" to the body tag, and then a jQuery script like this, I'd expect the site to fade in smoothly. But it does not work.
    $('.lazy').fadeIn('fast');

Comment: Your whole site... or your whole page?

Comment: The whole page. And all pages that have the lazy class on the body tag.

Comment: search in google about preloader instead use lazyload to load whole page. Lazy load isnt design for such purpose I guess

Comment: Good point. Maybe preloader is the better term. I'm not actually using any lazy-load scripts

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a 'main' js file that is being loaded in all pages, then you can do

```
$('body').fadeOut(0);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is this (here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsRBN/)):

CSS:

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to fire, but I'll keep testing it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to hide the page as soon as it is executed, and then show it again when the page is ready (onLoad) as suggested by php_nub_qq. You might vary this and wait till some other thing is ready like images are downloaded. However if you had a slow/mobile browser it might happen that the page appears in the browser, then the javascript executes and hides and then shows the page leading to nasty flickering.

You could use Javascript and css in combination as suggested by Josh Beam but if the user has javascript disabled they will never see anything because the "fadeIn" never fires.

However you might be better to consider why is it you need to display the page all at once? Perhaps one of your page resources/plugins is slow and you should fix that. Perhaps you should change to a single page app style of front end if a really specific type of user experience is required with very high performance needs.

Fundamentally you are trying to do something that is probably be best left to the browser, and it may have unintended side affects in terms of SEO, user experience and cross browser compatibility that should be considered before you apply any of the above.

Comment: good questions. I realize there might be unintended results, which I why I wanted to experiment with this.  My site is a wordpress site, that loads in a jerky fashion, due to masonry I think.  I was hoping to smooth it out. See: [link](http://topheavypilesofbooks.com/)

Comment: Having had a quick look I would try removing your large background image and see if that helps. On my machine it took over 1s to load it which does not help make the site feel snappy